# How to get number of rows affected by last several sql statement inside procedure in teradata?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, rows, teradata

So let I have 3 merge statement inside the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Employee(OUT num_rows BIGINT)
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO t1
         USING t2
    ...;
    MERGE INTO a1
         USING b2
    ...;
    MERGE INTO c1
         USING d2
    ...;
END;
```

How can I get number of rows affected inside procedure? I know about [ACTIVE_COUNT](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_109A/ch04.06.21.html), but can I use it? Is that `num_rows = ACTIVE_COUNT` will work, or need to add it to variable several times and initially set to 0?

Comment: Sounds pretty easy to try...

Comment: You need to initialize a variable to zero and then add the count (Either using `ACTIVITY_COUNT` or the `GET DIAGNOSTICS ROW_COUNT`) after each execution of a DML statement.

Comment: Thank you a lot @dnoeth, you can post it as a solution, so I can choose it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize a variable to zero and then add the count (Either using ACTIVITY_COUNT or the GET DIAGNOSTICS ROW_COUNT) after each execution of a DML statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Employee(OUT num_rows BIGINT)
BEGIN
   DECLARE ac BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

    MERGE INTO t1
         USING t2
    ...;
   SET ac = ac + ACTIVITY_COUNT;

    MERGE INTO a1
         USING b2
    ...;
   SET ac = ac + ACTIVITY_COUNT;

    MERGE INTO c1
         USING d2
    ...;
   SET ac = ac + ACTIVITY_COUNT;

   SET num_rows = ac;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the below piece after each of your merge.

```
Merge INTO t1
      USING t2
.....;

SET lv_activity_count = activity_count;


SET lv_message = ' Number of rows merged in table1 is  '|| lv_activity_count ;
..
```

Please initialise and declare the variables as well.

Comment: :) .. nono the signature came in the same line .. :). Corrected it.